# Databases Not Showing in Dashboard Designer Sharepoint 2013

Tags: dashboard-designer-2013

Development environment:

WFE - SP2013
SQL Server - SQL2014 [used to store SP dbs]
SQL Server - DATACUBE [used to store Contoso Datacube]

We are trying to connect PerformancePoint to the DATACUBE.  The databases aren't showing in the dropdown for Dashboard Designer.

[image: Dashboard Designer Blank]

Things I've tried/tested:

- I have installed MS SQL ADMOD.NET for 2014 on ALL servers.
- I have rebooted all servers.
- Given Unattended Service Account **sysadmin** permissions on both SQL servers
- Given Unattended Service Account **Site Collection Administrator** permissions on the Business Intelligence Center site

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: do you have SQL Service Analysis Service running ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

When I updated the web.config file, I used **oldVersion=11.0.0.0** and **newVersion=12.0.0.0.**

This wasn't correct.

I checked the logs and found the **oldVersion=10.0.0.0** so I changed the web.config file to **oldVersion=10.0.0.0** and the **newVersion=12.0.0.0**.

After doing an IISReset, it work perfectly.

So make sure you note what ***your*** version number.

Answer (score 0):

This setup is always confusing.  The account you need to use for the Unattended account is the service account, not the account that is defined in the Secure Stores (you would use the stored account option for that).

You need to be sure it's added as an admin to the SSAS instance hosting the cube.

To catch any other issues run ULS viewer and watch it live as you attempt to access the cube.  You can also run profiler on the SQL instance to check authentication.